# What is the scope of Google-Appscript's PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a GMail Add-on and I am currently using PropertiesService.getUserProperties() to save some configuration data. Recently however, we have a need to share configuration data for all users in the same domain. And I was thinking of using the PropertiesService.getScriptProperties() to do so.

I would just like to ask a question related to the following documentation on Google's apps script :

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service

For properties set using the scriptProperties.setProperty() API, will the property set be shared with all users regardless of domain? Or only users under the same domain will share the same value?

So for example, 2 unrelated domains (domain1.com and domain5.com) installed my GMail Add-on.  user1@domain1.com sets the add-on scriptproperty "url" to "google.com", will user2@domain5.com see the url as "google.com" as well? Or only users under domain1.com will be able to see "url" as "google.com".

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use Script Properties to restrict access to Properties Service data to only one domain.  You'll probably need to get the domain name of the user when the code runs, and if the user is in the domain, then run special code to access settings somewhere for that domain.

The settings specific to the domain could be put in various places, including your Script Properties.  But the problem with using Script Properties could be storage quota depending upon how much data you need to store.  If it's small amount of data, like whether that domain has paid there subscription or not and the date, then definitely put it in Script Properties.  But if you had lots of subscribers, then you'd want to have an external storage somewhere.

The domain name can be retrieved with the following code:

In order to use the below code, you'll need 3 scopes in your appsscript.json manifest file.

"oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"]

CODE:

```
var users = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
var urls = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo";

var params = {
  method : "get",
  headers : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urls, params);

if (response && response.getResponseCode() !== 200) {//There should always be a response unless the
  //Fetch call failed and if that happens then the outer try - catch can handle it

  return false;
}
var userinfo = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

Logger.log(userinfo)

var domainName = userinfo.hd ? userinfo.hd : false;

return domainName;
//userinfo["given_name"];//First Name
//userinfo["name"];//Full Name
//userinfo["id"];
//userinfo["family_name"];
//userinfo["email"];
//userinfo["picture"];//Link to profile image
//userinfo["locale"];//ID of country de = Germany
```

Comment: Hello Alan, thank you for taking time to share this with me. Your solution is the same as my original plan, to get the domain name of the user and then send it to my remote server via an API which takes this domain name and return the config-blob for that organization. I was just curious if I can use the script properties to store data which all users in the same domain can use. In this way, I was thinking only one person can set the scriptproperty, and everyone else shares/uses it. Thank you again.

Comment: All users in the same domain can access the same Script Property.  Other users and other domains could access it also, but as long as your code only runs for that domain, then you are restricting it through your code.  Script properties can be viewed by the owner of the Apps Script Project without code, but the user of the add-on can't view the Script Properties or access them.

Answer (score 1):

**When you are setting a property using the `setProperties(properties)` method, the property is set for the script itself.**

According to the documentation:

> `setProperties(properties)`
>
> Sets all key-value pairs from the given object in the current Properties store.

Therefore, if your concern is related to *which users* can access these properties, this is win fact related to the sharing permissions you have set for the script itself.

For instance, when sharing a script, you have the following options:

- **restricted**
- **sharing only with your organization**
- **anyone who was the link can access the script**

[image: sharing options]

As well as:

- **viewer**
- **editor**

[image: permissions]

You can also fiddle with these permissions programmatically by checking the [`Access Enum`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/access) and the [`Permission Enum`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/permission)

#### Reference

- [Properties Class Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties);
- [Apps Script Access Enum](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/access);
- [Apps Script Permission Enum](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/permission).

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. I have updated the question to reflect that this question was in the context of GMail add-ons. It is still Google-appscript though. So that being said, does the concept "sharing options" still apply? Thank you very much again.